# Read file into multidimensional arraylist with different datatypes?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm writing my first android app and so I am a newbie that's confused about the best way to get data from a file into an array.  I'm trying to get data from a resource raw txt file and store it in an array or `ArrayList` so I can perform an excel style vlookup. The data file (`data_file.txt`) is 28,2 in size and column one has an int and column 2 has a float separated via a space like this:

- 500 -1.3
- 1000 -1.6
- 10000 -1.7

I want to be able to look up the value of 1000 and get -1.6. 
Firstly should I be using a multidimensional object array or an `ArrayList` and is it important which one I use?  I need to keep the second column of data type float and would like to keep the first column data type int if possible.

I'm looking for tips on code and/or what methods I need to be researching.

Cheers,

Airfix

---

Update April 3rd

I'm pretty sure the map is not what I want.  I've been working on the code below.  It seems like it is going to work except the `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));`  I get a "cannot resolve constructor `FileReader(int)` over the file variable. Obviously it sees my file as an int when indeed it is just a plain txt file as shown in the example.  Still looking for help to complete.  Thanks :)

```
public void fuelIndex (){


    Object file = (getResources().getIdentifier("fuel_index",
                "raw", getPackageName()));
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));


    Object[][] fuelIndexData = new String[28][2];


    int i = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        fuelIndexData[i] = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        i++;
    }
    //loops through the file and splits on any space

    for (int row = 0; row < fuelIndexData.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < fuelIndexData[0].length; col++) {
            if(fuelIndexData[row][col] != null){
                System.out.print(fuelIndexData[row][col] + " " );
            }
        }
        if(fuelIndexData[row][0] != null){
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you only have a key and a value, maybe you could use a HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a use case for a `Map` instead of a `List`. Note: In Java there are two floating point data types.  You mentioned that you wanted to store the value as a float, but I assume you simply meant the data would be stored using floating-point representation. So, I'll assume we're working with `Double`s here. 
A `Map` can be used to map an `Integer` key to a `Double` value, as in using `map.get(1000)` to obtain the value 1.6.

Here's some code to demonstrate:

```
    Map<Integer,Double> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1000, 1.6);
    map.put(500,  1.3);
    map.put(10000, 1.7);

    System.out.println(map.get(10000));
    System.out.println(map.get(99));
```

This produces the following output:

```
1.7
null
```

1.7 was returned in the first call since it is the value for the 10000 key. `null` was returned in the second call since 99 was not in the keySet. The [JavaDoc for the Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) have many more details.

Comment: I'll have to think about if Mapping like this will work.  I'm picking up a user input from an edittext field.  This user input can be any integer within the data set range of the integer column and not necessarily one of the 'indices' listed.  All float values are the same for integer values between 1 and 500, 501 and 1000 etc.  I was going to use a loop to check what range the edittext input value fell into and then assign the corresponding float to a variable.  It seems that from my other programming experience (non object based) that an array would be the way to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the integers are unique and used to identify the float value, you should use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), if you are indexing by the position in the list and the integer values are allowed to have duplicates you can use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) with some object `ContainerObject` that stores both values.

**HashMap**

```
Map<Integer, Float> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
myMap.put(500, -1.3f);
myMap.put(1000, -1.6f);
myMap.put(10000, -1.7f);
```

**ArrayList**

```
List<ContainerObject> myList = new ArrayList<ContainerObject>();
myList.add(new ContainerObject(500, -1.3f));
myList.add(new ContainerObject(1000, -1.6f));
myList.add(new ContainerObject(1000, -1.7f));
```